# Не видит функцию

Tags: javascript, функции, select

```js
function GetData()
  {
     // получаем индекс выбранного элемента
   var selind = document.getElementById("SelectMyLove").options.selectedIndex;
   var txt= document.getElementById("SelectMyLove").options[selind].text;
   var val= document.getElementById("SelectMyLove").options[selind].value;

   alert("Теxt= "+ txt +" " + "Value= " + val);
}
```

```html
<SELECT onChange='GetData' name="SelectMyLove" id="SelectMyLove" >
<OPTION SELECTED VALUE="0">Выбираем любимый фрукт</OPTION>
<OPTION  VALUE="1">Абрикос</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="2">Персик</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="3">Слива</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="4">Груша</OPTION>
</SELECT>
```

В браузере пишет

> Uncaught ReferenceError: GetData is not defined

Comment: onChange='GetData()'

Comment: Не помогает,та же ошибка

Comment: закономерный вопрос - где находится функция `GetData`?

Comment: вставьте в страницу `<script>alert(window.GetData);</script>` сразу после `<script src="..."></script>`. Что происходит?

Answer (score 0):

А если добавить скобки?

```js
function GetData()
  {
     // получаем индекс выбранного элемента
   var selind = document.getElementById("SelectMyLove").options.selectedIndex;
   var txt= document.getElementById("SelectMyLove").options[selind].text;
   var val= document.getElementById("SelectMyLove").options[selind].value;

   alert("Теxt= "+ txt +" " + "Value= " + val);
}
```

```html
<SELECT onChange='GetData()' name="SelectMyLove" id="SelectMyLove" >
<OPTION SELECTED VALUE="0">Выбираем любимый фрукт</OPTION>
<OPTION  VALUE="1">Абрикос</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="2">Персик</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="3">Слива</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="4">Груша</OPTION>
</SELECT>
```

Comment: Все равно ошибка

Comment: так тут все отрабатывает, попробуйте выполнить код.

Comment: А данная функция где размещена?

Comment: он в файле который подключен к html

Comment: во первых, попробуй вставь в html ку код, в теги `<script></script>`, если отрабатывает, значит с подключением файла проблемы, с путями и т.п.

Comment: в тегах отрабатывает, но ведь други функции работают в подключаемом файлк

Comment: ну я об этом же не знал :) а можешь хотя б скрин куска js скинуть?

Comment: не совсем понял какого именно?

Comment: @Сергей74rus у вас есть файл js, там эта функция, нужно посмотреть ее расположение и как она определена

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67381/discussion-between-74rus-and-maxkrasnov).

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте в Ваш js файл рядом с функцией `GetData`

```
$("#SelectMyLove").change(GetData);
```

и уберите `onChange` из разметки.